# Why does ImageMagick from MacPorts does not work, when imagemagick from Homebrew does

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, imagemagick

I have fixed my error by installing through `Homebrew` but I would like to know: why does `homebrew` work but `macports` does not??

If I install ImageMagick from MacPorts I get this error even though I can call "`convert`" from the command line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .api import MagickPixelPacket, libc, libmagick, library
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/wand/api.py", line 205, in <module>
    'Try to install:\n  ' + msg)
ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
Try to install:
  port install imagemagick
```

Which I already did!

If I install via `homebrew`, I can no longer use "`convert`" from the command line but it plays well with `wand` from `PIP`.  Why is that?

Comment: Macports only has Imagemgick 6. Hombrew has ImageMagick 7. For ImageMagick 6, use convert. For ImageMagick 7 use magick for the main command. You wand may only play nicely with IM 7. Perhaps it was upgraded from using IM 6 to IM 7. It is also possible that MacPorts linked to a bad version of ImageMagick 6.